# Removing Friends information from Klout when account is unlinked

Tags: facebook

At some point, my Facebook account was enabled (was testing something) and well after that I decided to remove it. I would assume when one unlinks an account, **all information** that came with gets removed too.
This seems to not be the case.

So I went into my Facebook Application settings and noticed that the Klout
application is still there. I removed the application and was presented with

> If you remove Klout, it will no longer have access to your data and be removed from your profile, bookmarks, and Apps Page.

Good, go back to klout.com, friends are still there.

Okay, maybe the pictures are just cached go Incognito (/logout out of Facebook, stayed logged into
Twitter for OAuth), the Facebook friends are still there.

Okay... let's block the Klout app.

> Blocking Klout will prevent others from sending you invitations and requests for this app and will prevent this app from getting any info about you. This will also prevent you from seeing Klout if other people have it installed.

Good, requests don't work but you still have the data.

**So, how does one remove information from Klout after unlinking a specific account? Or is this how data is supposed to be handled?**

Answer (score 1):

To unlink a network in Klout you have to:

- Log in to Klout
- Click the Gears icon
- Select `Connect Networks`
- Click the `Unlink` link next to the network you want to delete e.g. Facebook

This only stops Klout from collecting any further data from that network.  It appears there is no way through the website to remove the data that has previously been collected.

According to a few Klout support articles, [like this one](http://support.klout.com/customer/portal/articles/156667-how-do-i-remove-a-specific-network-from-my-klout-account-), the best way to get a definitive answer is to [email them directly](http://mailto%3acontact@klout.com) with your request.